# Разница между интерфейсом и абстрактным классом

Tags: java

Мне не совсем понятно назначение абстрактных классов и интерфейсов. Зачем нужно использовать абстрактные классы, если есть интерфейсы?

Comment: Интерфейсы используются для описания поведения класс.
А от абстрактные классы используются для частичной реализации.

Answer (score 3):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33957698/6716519) есть ответ который, как мне кажется, более чем замечательный. Там есть несколько пунктов для `interface` и `abstract class`, которые помогут вам определиться, какой из них использовать.

В целом, я думаю, что о различиях вы уже в курсе:

В **абстрактных классах** можно использовать все, что и в классах, + можно добавлять `abstract`-методы (без реализации) и нельзя создать экземпляр абстрактного класса.

В **интерфейсах** нельзя использовать поля (с `java8`, если не ошибаюсь, есть возможность определять поля, но они будут статическими) и определять поведение функций по умолчанию (с `java8` появились `default`-методы).

Что касается выбора одного или другого:

Выбирайте **интерфейс**, когда вы просто дергаете одинаковые методы на совершенно разных объектах. Как пример - машина и самолёт. У них есть метод `move()`, который описан в соответствующем интерфейсе. И вам совершенно не нужно знать, что это за объект. Вы видите его как `Movable` и лишь двигаете.

Выбирайте **абстрактный класс** тогда, когда у объектов много общего, и есть такие методы, реализация которых идентична. Это могут быть легковая машина и грузовик. Метод `rotateWheels()` может иметь одну и ту же реализацию, и в целом в классах будут лишь малые различия. Тогда выбирайте абстрактный класс `Car`, в котором закладываете базовую реализацию, и дальше наследуетесь.

Comment: замечательный пример!)