# Разница между интерфейсом и абстрактным методов в java

Tags: java, ооп

Изучаю java и дошел до темы ООП, и тут описывается интерфейс и абстрактный метод, и я не совсем понимаю их разницу, ведь оба служат для каркаса(ну или чертежа, если я правильно понял) следующих методов, но искренне не могу понять разницу между ними и какой лучше использовать. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: От интерфейсов возможно множественное наследование. От абстрактных классов - нет. Всегда используйте интерфейсы. В случае необходимости - абстрактные классы. Необходимость бывает очень редко.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопросов: [Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса (abstract class and interface) - 2013](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235352/); [Разница между интерфейсом и абстрактным классом (дубликат) - 2018](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805359/)